Travel Requirements from Singapore to Mexico City
I would be traveling with a Ghanaian passport from Singapore to Mexico City via Turkish Airlines.
Does anybody know if I need to get any additional document aside a valid passport and a Mexican visa?
Or possibly point me to a website I could get these information from?

IATA Travel Centre, TravelDoc, Emirates simplified interface to Timatic

Are both flights on a single ticket, or are they booked separately?

@jcaron OP stated that they're flying Turkish all the way, so we can infer it's a single booking.

There are two separate tickets. Ticket one from Accra, Ghana to Singapore, then ticket two from Singapore to Mexico. Ghana has a 30 day VISA free access to Singapore.

Since you're flying on Turkish Airlines, you will transit in Istanbul (IST).  As long as your connection is less than 24 hours, as a Ghanaian citizen you will not need a transit visa. Timatic via Emirates:

TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
Passengers transiting through Ankara (ESB), Antalya (AYT), Istanbul:
Metropolitan Area (IST) and Sabiha Gokcen (SAW), or Izmir (ADB) with a
confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24
hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport
and have documents required for the next destination.

You will also need a visa for your destination (Mexico), but since you state you already have this, you'll be fine.
